# Listing of custom extension in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I have a backend module on my website. In this backend module, I need to list all the custom plugins that I am used in the website. I have no idea to list all the custom plugins.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom plugins"? Content elements with a special plugin?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is lacking important data, like what TYPO3 Version you are using.
In addition it is unclear if you mean plugins or extension. My guess is that you mean extensions.

In the case you need all extensions that are not "TYPO3 System Extensions" you can do something like this in your Controller I guess:

```php
$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
$listUtility = $objectManager->get(ListUtility::class);
$allExtensions = $listUtility->getAvailableExtensions();
$customExtensions = [];
foreach ($allExtensions as $key => $f) {
    if (is_dir(Environment::getPublicPath() . '/typo3/sysext/' . $key . '/')) {
        continue;
    }
    $customExtensions[$key] = $f;
    $customExtensions[$key]['isLoaded'] = (int)ExtensionManagementUtility::isLoaded($key);
}
$this->view->assign('extensions', $customExtensions);
```

If you want to exclude other extensions too you have to adopt the logic, like checking for the $key to and continue in that case.

Note: The answer needs a basic understanding how TYPO3 Development with Extbase work.

Comment: HI@Kevin Appelt Thanks for your replay. I used the same code. The code is working to display all the extension including t3 repository extensions like news,dce, etc. My requirement is to display only the extension that I am created in my website.

Comment: Yes, as I said you might need to adopt the logic to your needs. Maybe your extension keys all start with „xy“ then you can filter only these extensions. You might want to have a look into $f which contains the information given in the ext_emconf.php where you might be able to filter by author_name or author_company or alike.

Answer (score 1):

To list all plugins of your extension (inserted via TYPO3 backen) you can use a simple SQL Query

select from tt_content where CType="list" and list_type="your_plugin "

But you should not use raw queries but rather use the QueryBuilder as it provides additional security and enhances your query with restrictions like deleted.